# PHP Select highlited/formatted rows from CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have CSV file in which some rows are highlighted yellow colored, Is there anyway we can select highlighted rows through PHP script like we read any CSV file in PHP but with condition of formatting color.
Thanks

Comment: tell us what you have tried

Comment: I you open the CSV file in notepad, how do you recognise the yellow rows?

Comment: I'm afraid CSV has no cell formatting. You might see the formatting in, say, Microsoft Excel but when you plainly export the spreadsheet to CSV the formatting will be not saved in the CSV file.

Comment: Yes, you are right we cannot recognize yellow or highlighted rows in csv or xlsx format in notepad etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the "colored rows" is a functionality of Excel/Spreadsheet software.  The technical specification for a .CSV (comma-separated values) file does not include styling elements (colored or highlighted rows).  (See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180 )

You can see this if you open up your CSV file in a text editor (Notepad, Notepad++, vim, emacs, etc.) the content will be displayed, but no highlighting.  This is very similar to how PHP (and other programs) see the file.

One work around to this would be to add a new field to the file (Another column in Excel) which you would have to set to a value, and then look for that value when you move through the file in your php code.  For example  in a new column, put a `1` in any row which is highlighted.  Then within your PHP code, when you a reading in that .CSV file, look for a `1` in that new column, and that would be your "highlighted" row.